# Application with payment functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could you please refer me to an example of an Asp.Net application that would allow the owner to collect a fee for viewing certain pages content?
I have no idea what to start with. Besides the technical aspect of this question, I don't know where one would get a server to install such an application. Can any computer work as such?
Thanks, and sorry if my question is too naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for payment gateways. They will provide you with an API to call that can process the payments. An example would rely on the payment gateway that you are using as all of them are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I choose between AIM, SIM, etc.?

Comment: You need to look at a few things. First, you should really have have a secure site. If not then that will point you where to look next (hosted option or API). Secondly, you need to then look at which gateways support your country and the lastly, look at the rates and decide which is the best option.

Comment: If you are able to use authorize.net then that's definitely one of the better ones. They have good rates and a comprehensive API.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) it is quite developer friendly (you won't have to trawl through loads of docs to find out what you want to do) and the rates arn't too bad. They are similar to sagepay (much harder to figure out, out of date)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is Stripe better than what Graymatter suggested?

Comment: Stripe is a payment gateway just like what Graymatter mentioned.